# Designing F# types with hidden underlying implementations from interface

Tags: f#, immutability, underlyingtype

I'm new to F# and in an attempt to design some types, I noticed how much OOP has affected my design decisions. I had a hard time searching for this particular problem and came up empty-handed.

I will describe what I am trying to do in C# since I am more familiar with the terminology. Let us say that I have an interface specifying some minimal required methods on a container-like class. Let's call it `IContainer`. Then I have two classes that implement this interface, `ContainerA` and `ContainerB` with different underlying implementations that are hidden from users. This is a very common OOP pattern.

I am trying to achieve the same thing in F# only with immutable types to stay in the functional world, i.e. how can I implement a type where its functionality is interchangeable, but the public functions that users will use remain the same:

```
type 'a MyType = ...

let func1 mytype = ...
let func2 mytype -> int = ...
```

The definition of MyType is not known and can later be changed, e.g. if a more efficient version of the functions are found (like a better implementation of a container type), but without much effort or requiring a redesign of the entire module. One way is to use pattern matching in the functions and a discriminated union, but that does not seem very scalable.

Comment: So are you trying to do the exact same thing in F#, because you can implement classes and interfaces in it.

Comment: Yes. One possibility is to copy the design entirely from C# to F# but then the  underlying implementation must be part of the derived classes. Should functions operating on the containers then call `container.IsEmpty` for example? And how can I design the classes/types so that `let add ... =` will not modify the state of the object?

Comment: It is unclear if you are attempting to do OOP in F#, or if you are rethinking the problem through a functional lens. Do you want to accomplish what an interface does, but in the F# idiomatic way, or do you want a literal interface in the code?

Comment: If all you are doing is re-doing the OOP design in F#, I see very little point in going to F# in the first place. Yes, it is possible, but beyond that? It is quite likely that you use case lends itself to a functional solution, but you have given very little context - in fact, the context provided is your OOP design. Can you say a bit more?

Comment: A very broad question. I strongly recommend 1) "The F# Component Design Guidelines" below Documentation on fsharp.org, and 2) site titled F# for fun and profit, in order to get your answers.

Comment: @BryanWatts: I would like a functional, F# idiomatic approach to the same problem. BentTranberg: I've looked at many of those and still not found a clear way to do it. AntonSchwaighofer: I'll try and update my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is more typical in functional languages to use far simpler types than you would in an OO language.

Modelling shapes is the classic example.

Here is a typical OO approach:

```
type IShape =
     abstract member Area : double

type Circle(r : float) =
     member this.Area = System.Math.PI * r ** 2.0
     interface IShape with
         member this.Area = this.Area

type Rectangle(w : float, h : float) =
     member this.Area = w * h
     interface IShape with
         member this.Area = this.Area
```

Notice that it's very easy to add new types using this approach, we could introduce a `Triangle` or a `Hexagon` class with relatively little effort.  We simply create the type and implement the interface.

By contrast, if we wanted to add a new `Perimeter` member to our `IShape`, we would have to change every implementation which could be a lot of work.

Now let's look at how we might model shapes in a functional language:

```
type Shape =
    |Circle of float
    |Rectangle of float * float

[<CompilationRepresentation (CompilationRepresentationFlags.ModuleSuffix)>]
module Shape =
    let area = function
        |Circle r -> System.Math.PI * r ** 2.0
        |Rectangle (w, h) -> w*h
```

Now, hopefully you can see that it's much easier to add a `perimeter` function, we simply pattern match against each `Shape` case and the compiler can check whether we've implemented it exhaustively for every case.

By contrast, it's now far more difficult to add new `Shape`s because we have to go back and change every function which acts upon `Shape`s.

The upshot is, whatever form of modelling we choose to use, there are trade-offs.  This problem is called *The Expression Problem*.

---

You can easily apply the second pattern to your `Container` problem:

```
type Container =
    |ContainerA
    |ContainerB

let containerFunction1 = function
    |ContainerA -> ....
    |ContainerB -> ....
```

Here you have a single type with two or more cases and the unique implementation of functionality for each case is contained in module functions, rather than the type itself.

Comment: I like the view of the trade-offs between the OO and FP paradigms, and I wasn't aware of the expression problem. Thanks! And thanks to all the other helpful commenters!

Comment: @NordCoder It's worth noting that there other solutions to the problem.  If you have a good system for ad-hoc polymorphism (namely type-classes/traits), that opens up another alternative.  .NET doesn't have support for them at the moment, although a mechanism for implementing them was recently demonstrated.

Comment: I'm aware of that and actually my F# code is inspired by a Haskell library that makes use of typeclasses to achieve this. It is my understanding that the F# "typeclass" implementation is a bit limited compared to Haskell's, but correct me if I'm wrong.